# Managing Multiple Sublime Python Builds

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3

I've created a few build configurations for a Python project I'm working on in Sublime, and I'm able to run them no problem.

I was wondering if there was a way of managing running multiple builds at the same time. I can run a second build after the first one, and it does seem to successfully launch that python process - however, it overwrites the terminal with the second build that I ran, and I have no way of knowing the status of the first process. I can see it in task manager, though.

Is there a way of seeing the status of multiple builds, or should I stick to running one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, Sublime build systems are executed by using the built in `exec` command. One of the things that the `exec` command does is manage the contents of the build output panel. That command is what is clearing the contents of the build output panel at the start of every build. There's no direct setting you can apply to have the command keep the previous build output in the panel, however.

It's possible to add a `target` key in a `sublime-build` file, which tells Sublime to use a command other than `exec` to execute the build. So you could create a custom command similar to (and/or based on) the default `exec` command that wouldn't clear the output panel between runs if you wanted to, although that requires some knowledge of how plugins in Sublime work. Potentially there is a package or plugin already available on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) that already does this.

Depending on how you're executing your builds and what they do, a potential workaround to this that doesn't involve writing a plugin would be to create a build that executes multiple commands one after the other, so that they all execute in a chain from within a single build.

Comment: can you create multiple build output panels, or is there only one?

Comment: A plugin could create as many of them as it wanted to, but the default `exec` command always reuses (and only sends output to) the default one. There also may or may not be some interplay between the commands that navigate between errors and having more than one build output panel, I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: ok, looks like I'll have to look into plugins then. I assume there's ways for making panels persistent, showing multiple panels and tabbing them, etc.?

Comment: Yep; panels are persistent by nature, so once you create one it lives until Sublime restarts or you remove it via plugin code. All panels show up in the panel switcher (bottom left of the status bar) and can be opened and closed with the built in commands as well.

Comment: I came across this - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Exec%20In%20Window

Do you think this works for what I want to do? and would I need to update/modify it for sublime 3?

edit: can't install it in sublime 3. I should be able to write something similar following this source for sublime 3 though

Comment: There is a [porting guide](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html) in the official documentation that may be of assistance in getting that package to work in Sublime 3. Package Control won't let you install it because it's marked as ST2 only, but you may have more luck installing it manually.